# Error with initial push with Github and Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I use github with two accounts. I was able to use to push Android Studio project with "VCS -> Import Into Version Control ->Share Project on GitHub".
Then I changed my user (in Github desktop and Android Studio GitHub settings) and now I can't push my projects anymore. 
I get this error:

*Can't finish GitHub sharing process*

*Successfully created project '{ProjectName}' on GitHub, but initial push failed: unable to access 'https://github.com/{User}/{ProjectName}.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403*

As the error says the repo is created on my GitHub account, but it is empty. I know that *error 403* stands for *forbidden*, but it doesn't make any sense to me.. How is it possible that it can create a repo but has no permission to push the files there?

Is there any configuration outside AndroidStudio that I should change in order to achieve this?

Comment: Are you allowed to do push/pull to desired remote? You can check that from github repo setting -> collaborators

Comment: you are facing this empty repo field because, your project files .git init have reference to both your logins. so it's confused. use command line tools , remove old .git files from your repo and add new one using git init and other git command line tools .

Comment: Thanks to both of you. @HourGlass I did the initial commit and push using command line and it worked.. I followed [this simple guide](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/) but noticed that the command `$ git add .` add all the files including some that usually are not added (like gradle files). Do you know which files should I manually exclude using (I think) `$ git reset HEAD YOUR-FILE`??  Thanks again!

Comment: there will be .gitignore file in your project , which will have list of files which git should avoid adding to github. modify as you like it, like which files you want to be excluded to add into git. @Marcos

Comment: My problem was related to keychain access as i am using mac. You need to check the git username and password weather its right or wrong.